# Docker container apt-get install can't find package

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to spin up a docker container that populates mongo via a node.js script that I have.

With the script below, I get the error :

```
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs
 ---> Running in 7ed0f8e018e7
Get:1 http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg [1554 B]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release [102 kB]
Get:3 http://httpredir.debian.org wheezy Release.gpg [2373 B]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages [405 kB]
Get:5 http://httpredir.debian.org wheezy-updates Release.gpg [1554 B]
Get:6 http://httpredir.debian.org wheezy Release [191 kB]
Get:7 http://httpredir.debian.org wheezy-updates Release [143 kB]
Get:8 http://httpredir.debian.org wheezy/main amd64 Packages [7637 kB]
Get:9 http://httpredir.debian.org wheezy-updates/main amd64 Packages [5788 B]
Fetched 8490 kB in 5s (1444 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package nodejs
```

with this dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:2.6.11

ENV NODE_ENV docker

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Why does apt-get not find nodejs?

Comment: maybe `mongo:2.6.11` is based on an older distro?

Comment: Here's the dockerfile for mongo:2.6.11 https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/982328582c74dd2f0a9c8c77b84006f291f974c3/2.6/Dockerfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems i was missing `RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.10 | bash -` before the `apt-get install`

Answer (score 0):

As you use `debian:wheezy` based image you might want to check the **Note** on the older distros at https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: I actually want Node 0.10.40 and not 4.x

Comment: should not the package name be different then?

Comment: I was just trying other things. Both of these give the same result: `root@503229baf152:/# apt-get install -y nodejs        
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nodejs
root@503229baf152:/# apt-get install -y nodejs=0.10.40
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nodejs`

Comment: why don't you take plain ubuntu or something? It is generally a bad idea to install node at the same container as mongo besides more polished images tend to remove "unneeded" stuff which might cause things like you experience.

Comment: I have a node container already to run my node.js server. I want a mongo container and when i'm installing the mongo container, I want to populate the mongo database with json data in a node.js script. 

From my understanding of docker, if i have a CMD in my node.js container to populate mongo, I'm not sure how I can have a CMD to also start my node.js server since you can only have one CMD per container.

Comment: You have two containers and link them either via `--link` if they can talk over the network or via `--volumes-from` if then need to exchange files.

Comment: Yes i know how to link them, but would the population of mongo be done in a RUN or a CMD. Also can you specify a link when you're building a package or just when you're running it?